# How to check property with hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript

Does `hasOwnProperty()` check user-created objects only?

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // returns false
```

I want to know that `toString()` is used in which prototype?

```
String.hasOwnProperty('toString');// it's too returns false
Object.hasOwnProperty('toString');// it's too returns false
```

So, how to check `toString()` or something else is of what in prototype chain?

And also,

```
var myArr = ['a','b','c'];
myArr.hasOwnProperty('length');
// returns true, why? but it is of Array or Object...
```

Comment: try `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does `hasOwnProperty()` checks only user created objects only?

It works on all objects which have that method available on their prototype chain (all objects except certain host objects, namely some IE objects, and objects created with `Object.create(null)`, as well as a few other exotic ways).

`String` and `Object` don't have `toString()` on them directly by default (though you *can* assign itself, but this wouldn't be recommended).

They do, however, have it on their prototype chain. As the first property lookup matched is used and `String` is a constructor function, it will find it on `Function.prototype`. You can confirm this by executing...

```
String.toString == Function.prototype.toString
```

Other objects have their own `toString()`, depending on what makes the most sense in which context.

> ```
> var myArr = ['a','b','c'];
> myArr.hasOwnProperty('length');// returns true, why? but it is of Array or Object...
> ```

An array does have a `length` property directly on it.

If you want to know if an object has a property available on its prototype chain, you can use the `in` operator...

```
var hasProp = 'toString' in String;
```